# Why is Halloween the same as Christmas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, puzzle

Someone told me that Halloween was the same as Christmas and that it had something to do with math, is this a joke or does it actually have a mathematical basis?

Comment: It does have something of a mathematical basis.

Comment: " is this a joke or does it actually have a mathematical basis?"  Uh... both?

Comment: Missing context? What other context could I give? Also, this counts as a mathematical puzzle, so it would be about mathematics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OCT can be interpreted as octal (base 8) and $31_8 = 25_{10}$ (31 in base 8 is 25 in base 10). And DEC can be interpreted as decimal, so OCT 31 = DEC 25.

Comment: oh, that was .... funny. really don't know what to say